# Where can I find data for Formula 1 races and race cars

Tags: data-request, sports, historical

I am looking for dataset on the outcomes of Formula 1 races, what cars partook in the race, and the specifications of these cars (such as type of tire used; type of engine; width, length and other parameters that describe the shape of the car).

If the dataset contained information about the drivers as well as the weather conditions and geographic information of the race track that would be all the more better.

I can't seem to find any datasets on Formula 1 racing, so I was wondering if anyone could suggest one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct answer for your question, but you might find these links useful. Haven't tested it personally, but free for non-commercial use [Ergast API](http://ergast.com/mrd/) seems appropriate for building such a dataset. A commercial solution, [SportsAPI](https://sportsapi.com/) offers 14 days free of charge. You may use it to build such dataset.